# Ansible get tags info and facts from ec2 instances(Linux)

Tags: ansible

For windows we used a powershell script to get tags and facts and storing it in a variable.

```
---

- name: "Read Tags from the current Instance"
  win_shell: |
    $InstanceId = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id" -UseBasicParsing)
    $Instance = ((Get-EC2Instance -Instance $InstanceId).RunningInstance)
    $Instance = $Instance | Where-Object { $_.InstanceId -eq $InstanceId }
    ($Instance.Tags | Where-Object { $_.Key -eq "Namespace"}).Value
    ($Instance.Tags | Where-Object { $_.Key -eq "Application"}).Value
    ($Instance.Tags | Where-Object { $_.Key -eq "Environment"}).Value
    ($Instance.Tags | Where-Object { $_.Key -eq "Component"}).Value
    (Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 5 -Method Get -Uri "http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document").Region
  register: instance_output
  retries: 5
  delay: 2
  until: instance_output.changed
```

For Linux I tried using the below playbook

```
- name: check if we can get metadata
      uri:
        url: http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data
        timeout: 3
      register: meta_check
      failed_when: False

    - name: store result
      set_fact:
        inside_aws: "{{ meta_check.status == 200 }}"

    - name: install aws cli
      become: true
      command: yum install -y awscli
      when: inside_aws

    - name: get the list of tags
      shell: REGION=$(curl -q http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone) INSTANCE=$(curl -q http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id); aws ec2 describe-tags --region ${REGION%?} --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTANCE"
      register: tag_list
      when: inside_aws

    - name: create facts out of tags
      ignore_errors: true
      set_fact:
        "{{'ec2_tag_' + tag.Key.replace(':','_').replace('-','_') }}": "{{ tag.Value }}"
      with_items: "{{ (tag_list.stdout | from_json)['Tags'] }}"
      when: inside_aws
      loop_control:
        loop_var: tag
        label: "{{ tag.Key }} {{ tag.Value }}"
```

Basically I should store the below 5 tags

- namespace:
- application:
- environment:
- component:
- **For all instance we have above tags**
- Instance Region

Output of the above playbook (partial):

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tag_list.stdout": {
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Key": "Application",
                "ResourceId": "i-0cf3a8942e7b77ec",
                "ResourceType": "instance",
                "Value": "mac"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Business Unit",
                "ResourceId": "i-0cf3a894e7b77ec",
                "ResourceType": "instance",
                "Value": "trc"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Component",
                "ResourceId": "i-0cf3a894e7b77ec",
                "ResourceType": "instance",
                "Value": "tower"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Domain",
                "ResourceId": "i-0cf3a894e7b77ec",
                "ResourceType": "instance",
                "Value": "user.compio.io"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Environment",
                "ResourceId": "i-0cf3a894e7b77ec",
                "ResourceType": "instance",
                "Value": "ops1"
            },
```

I found a way to do this.

```
    - set_fact: Application="{{ tag_list.stdout | from_json | json_query('Tags[0].Value') }}"
    - set_fact: Component="{{ tag_list.stdout | from_json | json_query('Tags[2].Value') }}"
    - set_fact: Environment="{{ tag_list.stdout | from_json | json_query('Tags[4].Value') }}"
    - set_fact: Namespace="{{ tag_list.stdout | from_json | json_query('Tags[8].Value') }}"

    - debug: var=Application
    - debug: var=Component
    - debug: var=Namespace
    - debug: var=Environment
```

How can I use the key "Application" and find the "Value". So that i don't need Indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ec2_metadata_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ec2_metadata_facts_module.html) and [ec2_instance_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/ec2_instance_info_module.html#ec2-instance-info-module)

```
- name : Playbook to Check Tags
  hosts: "{{host}}"
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:
    - ec2_metadata_facts:
    - ec2_instance_facts:
        instance_ids: '{{ ansible_ec2_instance_id }}'
        region: '{{ ansible_ec2_placement_region }}'
      register: my_instance
      delegate_to: localhost
    - debug:
        msg: my tags "{{ my_instance.instances | map(attribute='tags.YOUR_TAG_NAME') | list | join('\n') }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

In case it will be helpful for anyone. I am pasting my code below.

I achieved by the instruction i got from @mdaniel. Thank you.

```
- ec2_metadata_facts:
  register: instance_meta
- ec2_instance_info:
    instance_ids:
      - "{{ instance_meta.ansible_facts.ansible_ec2_instance_id }}"
    region: "{{ instance_meta.ansible_facts.ansible_ec2_placement_region }}"
  register: instance_info

- name: Gather and Save Instance Info
  set_fact:
      Application: "{{ instance_info.instances | map(attribute='tags.Application') | list | join('\n') }}"
      Component: "{{ instance_info.instances | map(attribute='tags.Component') | list | join('\n') }}"
      Namespace: "{{ instance_info.instances | map(attribute='tags.Namespace') | list | join('\n') }}"
      Environment: "{{ instance_info.instances | map(attribute='tags.Environment') | list | join('\n') }}"
      Region: "{{ instance_meta.ansible_facts.ansible_ec2_placement_region }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you want is [`ec2_metadata_facts:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_metadata_facts_module.html) followed by [`ec2_instance_facts:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/aws/ec2_instance_facts_module.html) which helpfully returns the [tags as a `dict`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/aws/ec2_instance_facts_module.html#return-instances/tags)

```yaml
tasks:
- ec2_metadata_facts:
- ec2_instance_facts:
    instance_id: '{{ ansible_ec2_instance_id }}'
    region:  '{{ ansible_ec2_placement_region }}'
  register: my_instance
- debug:
    msg: my tags {{ my_instance.tags }}
```

Comment: Really helpfull @mdaniel

Comment: This is not working, You need to have double quote in msg.